# Associate two arrays according to a number of key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I would like to make an association between two arrays of objects and i am stuck with this.
Explanation :

I have an array of different reference products

```
const array1 = [
{name: peanuts, referenceKey: 0}, 
{name: almond, referenceKey: 1}, 
{name: nuts, referenceKey: 2}, 
{name: cream, referenceKey: 3}
]
```

I have another table with open reference products that have an expiration date and the same reference key as the one in the `array1` in addition to a specific key for each open product

```
const array2 = [
 {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 42}, 
 {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "20d", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 43}, 
 {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "15h", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 44}, 
 {name: almond, expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey:1, otherKey: 45},
 {name: cream, expirationDate: "1d", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 46},
 {name:cream, expirationDate: "12h", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 47}
]
```

What i would like to do is to calculate the number of same product of `array2` that are opened  and push this number in an new `array` based on `array1`, something like this:

```
const array3 = [
 {name: peanuts, referenceKey: 0, opened: 3}, 
 {name: almond, referenceKey: 1, opened: 1}, 
 {name: nuts, referenceKey: 2, opened: 0}, 
 {name: cream, referenceKey: 3, opened: 2}
]
```

I try to regroup the `array2` by name with Reduce() method like this :

```
    const groupByName = (products, name) => {
        return products.reduce((acc, obj) => {
            var key = obj[name];
            if (!acc[key]) {
                acc[key] = []
            }
            acc[key].push(obj);
            return acc
        }, [])
    };

    const groupByName = groupByReference(array2, "name")
    console.log(groupByName)
```

output of groupByName:

```
  [
    [peanuts:
    [
        {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 42}, 
        {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "20d", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 43}, 
        {name: peanuts, expirationDate: "15h", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 44}, 
    ],
    cream: [
        {name: cream, expirationDate: "1d", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 46 },
        {name: cream, expirationDate: "12h", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 47}
    ],
    almond: [
        {name: almond, expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey:1, otherKey: 45},
    ]
 ]
```

Then I try to retrieve the length of each array and i don't get it. I tried to use Map()
method but it's not working.

Even if i specify the index like this  `groupByName['peanuts']`, a console.log() return the right array. But using  `groupByName['peanuts'].length` is not working.

Comment: Probably just typos with the question, but just to point it out, `name: cream` is a syntax error if the value is not a variable.  If it is a literal then you forgot to put quotes in all those places.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object, both for generating the result set as well for counting same named objects.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ name: "peanuts", referenceKey: 0 }, { name: "almond", referenceKey: 1 }, { name: "nuts", referenceKey: 2 }, { name: "cream", referenceKey: 3 }],
    array2 = [{ name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 42 }, { name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "20d", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 43 }, { name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "15h", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 44 }, { name: "almond", expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey: 1,  otherKey: 45 }, { name: "cream", expirationDate: "1d", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 46 }, { name: "cream", expirationDate: "12h", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 47 }],
    temp = {},
    result = array1.map(o => temp[o.name] = { ...o, open: 0 });

array2.forEach(o => temp[o.name].open++);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array3 = array1
for( let element of array3 ) {
  element['opened'] = array2.filter(el => el.referenceKey == element.referenceKey).length  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your original request, I think this is what your after, if I've understood your question correctly.

You can group by either `name` or `referenceKey` as they exist in both arrays, but not `expirationDate`.

```js
const array1 = [
  { name: "peanuts", referenceKey: 0 },
  { name: "almond", referenceKey: 1 },
  { name: "nuts", referenceKey: 2 },
  { name: "cream", referenceKey: 3 },
];

const array2 = [
  { name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 42 },
  { name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "20d", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 43 },
  { name: "peanuts", expirationDate: "15h", referenceKey: 0, otherKey: 44 },
  { name: "almond", expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey: 1, otherKey: 45 },
  { name: "cream", expirationDate: "1d", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 46 },
  { name: "cream", expirationDate: "12h", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 47 },
];

const groupByKey = (products, instances, key) => {
  return products.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    // Count matching instances matching
    const opened = instances.filter((instance) => instance[key] === obj[key])
      .length;

    // Append to accumulator array, uses spread, for immutability.
    acc = [
      ...acc,
      {
        name: obj.name,
        referenceKey: obj.referenceKey,
        opened,
      },
    ];

    return acc;
  }, []);
};

const array3 = groupByKey(array1, array2, "name");
console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with a helper function that counts all objects that yield a given value when a supplied function is applied to them.  Something like

```js
countBy (x => x.a) ([{a: 'p', b: 'm'}, {a: 'q', b: 's'}, 
                     {a: 'p', b: 't'}, {a: 'r', b: 'v'}])
//=> {p: 2, q: 1, r: 1}
```

because two of the objects have an `a` value of `'p'`, one has `'q'` and one has `'r'`.

We can use this to count our objects by `referenceKey` (`name` should also work if it is supposed to be a string and not a reference to some object in the question) and then simply mapping over our definition objects, adding the appropriate `opened` property from that result (or `0` if we didn't find any.)

It could look like this:

```js
const countBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs.reduce((a, x, _, __, key = fn(x)) => ({...a, [key] : (a[key] || 0) + 1}), {})

const opened = (defs, instances, counts = countBy (x => x.referenceKey) (instances)) =>
  defs.map (def => ({...def, opened: counts[def.referenceKey] || 0}))


const array1 = [{name: 'peanuts', referenceKey: 0}, {name: 'almond', referenceKey: 1}, {name: 'nuts', referenceKey: 2}, {name: 'cream', referenceKey: 3}] 
const array2 = [{name: 'peanuts', expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 42}, {name: 'peanuts', expirationDate: "20d", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 43}, {name: 'peanuts', expirationDate: "15h", referenceKey:0, otherKey: 44}, {name: 'almond', expirationDate: "30d", referenceKey:1, otherKey: 45}, {name: 'cream', expirationDate: "1d", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 46}, {name: 'cream', expirationDate: "12h", referenceKey: 3, otherKey: 47}] 

console .log (opened (array1, array2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

---

But you were also on the right track.  You could use your `groupByName` (after you straighten out a naming problem between two definitions of `groupByName` and one of `groupByReference`) with something like this:

```js
const groupedByName = groupByName (array2, "name")

array1 .map (({name, ...rest}) => ({
  name, 
  ...rest, 
  opened: (groupedByName[name] || []).length
}))
```